# Spark : How to use mapPartition and create/close connection per partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

So, I want to do certain operations on my spark DataFrame, write them to DB and create another DataFrame at the end. It looks like this :

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val newDF = myDF.mapPartitions(
  iterator => {
    val conn = new DbConnection
    iterator.map(
       row => {
         addRowToBatch(row)
         convertRowToObject(row)
     })
    conn.writeTheBatchToDB()
    conn.close()
  })
  .toDF()
```

This gives me an error as mapPartitions expects return type of `Iterator[NotInferedR]`, but here it is `Unit`. I know this is possible with forEachPartition, but I'd like to do the mapping also. Doing it separate would be an overhead (extra spark job). What to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last expression in the anonymous function implementation must be the return value:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val newDF = myDF.mapPartitions(
  iterator => {
    val conn = new DbConnection
    // using toList to force eager computation - make it happen now when connection is open
    val result = iterator.map(/* the same... */).toList
    conn.writeTheBatchToDB()
    conn.close()
    result.iterator
  }
).toDF()
```

Comment: What if I have to use the `conn` inside `iterator.map()` function ? Won't I get a connection already closed exception?

Comment: Well - you're right - because of iterator.map's laziness, the actual calculation would only happen when the `result` iterator is used, hence - after the connection is closed. I'll fix the answer to reflect this - thanks

Comment: Thanks! I've asked it as a separate one. You may take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881042/spark-db-connection-per-spark-rdd-partition-and-do-mappartition

Comment: I would close it the same lazy way without toList: `(iterator.map(...) ++ Seq(null)).filter(_ != null || {  close ; false })`

Answer (score 14):

On most cases, eager consuming the iterator will result to execution failure if not slow down of jobs. Thus what I've done was to check if iterator is already empty then do the cleanup routines.

```
rdd.mapPartitions(itr => {
    val conn = new DbConnection
    itr.map(data => {
       val yourActualResult = // do something with your data and conn here
       if(itr.isEmpty) conn.close // close the connection
       yourActualResult
    })
})
```

Thought this as a spark problem at first but was a scala one actually. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html#isEmpty:Boolean